# Calling method from module

Tags: python, methods, import, serial-port, spyder

I'm new to python and have issues getting my code working.

I got two different modules, in module a.py I put all my methods, in module b.py I put the logic.

The development environment I'm using is Sypder.

```
# module a
import serial
ser = serial.Serial()
def serWrite ( str ):
    ser.write (str + "\x0D")
    print "Write data :",  str + "\x0D"  
    time.sleep(0.1)
    return

def configuration():
    flagAT = 0
    while (flagAT == 0):
        serWrite("at")
        while True:
            ok = ser.readline()
            if (ok[0:2] == "OK"):
                print ("AT OK, DEVICE CONNECTED" + "\x0D")
                flagAT = 1
                break
            else:
                   print "DEVICE NOT CONNECTED OR NOT WORKING"

                   break
    print("Starting with configuration")
```

Module b.py :

```
#module b
import serial
import a

ser = serial.Serial()
ser.port = "/dev/ttyS1"
ser.baudrate = 115200
### more serial configuration here###

try: 
    ser.open()
except Exception, e:
    print "error open serial port: " + str(e)
    exit()

configuration()
```

Now to the issue:
When I run module b.py AFTER running a.py INSIDE Spyder everything is working as intended.

BUT: Spyder code analysis tells me

```
'a' imported but unused
```

When I try to call module b.py OUTSIDE Spyder I get following error

```
pi@(none) ~/WorkingDirectory $ python b.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "b.py", line 83, in <module>
configuration()
NameError: name 'configuration' is not defined
```

Importing configuration() with:

```
import a
a.configuration()
```

Gives following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 540, in runfile
 execfile(filename, namespace)
 File "/home/workingDirectory/test.py", line 85,     in    <module>
a.configuration()
File "a.py", line 336, in configuration
serWrite("at")
File "a.py", line 16, in serWrite
ser.write (str + "\x0D")
File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/serial/serialposix.py", line 490, in write
serial.serialutil.SerialException: Attempting to use a port that is not open
```

I don't understand why my programm is running within spyder without problems but not outside.
Can someone help here?

Comment: You need `from a import configuration` in module b. Spyder did not produce error because you executed the two scripts in the **same** interpreter.

Comment: @HuazuoGao Isn't that equal to `import a` and then `a.configuration()` (which he said he thied doing in the question)?

Comment: @HuazuoGao this returns the same error as `import a`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change module b to:

```
#module b
import serial
from a import ser, configuration

#ser = serial.Serial()
ser.port = "/dev/ttyS1"
ser.baudrate = 115200
### more serial configuration here###

try: 
    ser.open()
except Exception, e:
    print "error open serial port: " + str(e)
    exit()

configuration()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This helped me a lot